# Html/CSS Disappearing div background

Tags: css, image, html

Few days ago i've noticed, that if a website have a background and if you overlap transparent PNG image on the div, the divs background disappears... Maybe it's only my computer rendering glitch, so I'll attach [Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KbK8n.jpg) too.

[JSbin for index and css](http://jsbin.com/eGUteTe)

Comment: Strange, I've never came across this problem before. What browser are you using?

Comment: Firefox. But I think this happens on Google Chrome too...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
body{ 
   background:url('image') no-repeat top left;
}
```

You should not use 'background' in HTML tag!!!!!

```
 html{
      background:url('image') no-repeat top left;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you don't have two images on top of each other? it seems like you have a colour image with a grey-scale image underneath.

If so, remove the bottom image.

EDIT: sorry, it seems to be an image change problem when you hover. Look at changing what the image switches to

Comment: It's changing on mouse over...
<img src="images/logo.png" width="420" height="248" 
     onmouseover="this.src='images/logo2.png';"
      onmouseout="this.src='images/logo.png';"/>

Comment: Your second image doesnt have a transparent background

Comment: It has. JSBin just does not allow to upload images. So i've used their logo. :) And if I remove picture changing, it still does this strange glitch...

Comment: Create a jsfiddle (jsfiddle.net) and I can take a look at your code